# Angular 5 services are initialized before APP_INITIALIZER is done

Tags: angular, angular5

I am converting an AngularJS 1.6 app to Angular 5, and I'm trying to figure out why my services are being initialized before the APP_INITIALIZER is done.

Context:

- I need to fetch the app config using httpClient before initializing the app
- All http requests need the app ID from the config fetched in order to resolve

**In AngularJS 1.6:**

Here I do an HTTP request to get the app config, and I store in a `.value()` so I can inject it in all of my app after bootstrapping it.

```
function getApp(): ng.IHttpPromise<Application> {
  const injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
  const $http: ng.IHttpService = injector.get('$http');
  const appSlug: string = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];

  return $http.get(`/v3/app/${appSlug}`, { headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' } });
}

getApp()
  .then((application) => {
    angular.module(app)
      .value('APP_CONFIG', angular.extend({}, application.data, ENV));

    bootstrap();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    alert('There was an error starting the app. Please try refreshing your browser.');
  });
```

**In Angular 5:**

Current behaviour:

- The news.service.ts class constructor is executed (this is where I need the app ID)
- The APP_INITIALIZER factory resolves (this is where I assign the app id to the app.provider.ts)
- The news.component.ts `ngOnInit` is called as expected (after the APP_INITIALIZER is done)

What is the strategy to achieve the same behaviour as my AngularJS 1.6 app?

**Code:**

*app.module.ts*

```
export function startupServiceFactory(appProvider: AppProvider): Function {
  return () => appProvider.load();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CoreModule,
    ColumnViewModule,

    NavBarModule,
    SideMenuModule,
    NewsModule,

    UIRouterModule.forRoot({ states: STATES }),
  ],

  providers: [
    AppProvider,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: startupServiceFactory, deps: [AppProvider], multi: true },
    SideMenuService,
  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.provider.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IApplicationConfig } from './app.interface';

@Injectable()
export class AppProvider {
  public APP_CONFIG: IApplicationConfig;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getAppConfig() {
    return this.APP_CONFIG;
  }

  public load(): Promise<any> {
    const appSlug: string = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http
        .get(`/v3/app/rca-dev-test`)
        .subscribe((response: IApplicationConfig) => {
          this.APP_CONFIG = response;
          resolve(true);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: given the async nature of http, I don't know if you can achieve this, because while your app is initializing you are trying to fetch data from server. You should put some logic inside ngOnInit on app_component to execute this logic and fetch and the set the data you want. If you really need this you must to try to manually bootstrap the app from inside the service.

Comment: APP_INITIALIZER expects a promise... so it should work, and it does, but not in the right order.

Comment: And adding login in all of my services to fetch this data is not the way to go and would add way to much duplicate code

Comment: You don't have to! Just fetch this data at App_component ngOnInit and store on service or localstorage, or cookies and use it when you need!

Comment: Also, you are storing this inside the same instace of the service, maybe is your problem.

Comment: That won't work... If I do an async call to get the app config in app.component, by the time I get the response, the `new.service` has been initialized. This is why I need that config before the entire app loads.

Comment: I've been following all the tutorials online: https://devblog.dymel.pl/2017/10/17/angular-preload/, https://hackernoon.com/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-add41a6b7e

Comment: Show your code for news.service.ts

Answer (score 0):

**This is how I do it:**

Store your settings as a JSON file in your assets folder.

EG:

```
{
  "apiUrl": "https://localhost:9001/api/v1"
}
```

*startupServiceFactory.ts*

```
export const startupServiceFactory = (appProvider: AppProvider) => () =>
  new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    await appProvider.load();
    resolve(true);
  });
```

*relevant code in appProvider.ts*

```
  public async load(): Promise<any> {
    this.appConfig = await this.http
    .get('assets/appSettings/appSettings.json')
    .pipe(shareReplay(1))
    .toPromise();
  }
```

Make sure to import shareReplay from rxjs/operators in appProvider.ts:

```
import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Your *app.module.ts* can stay the same, just import the `startupServiceFactory`.